# hive - Get date in mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: hive, timestamp, hql

Using Hive, I have date dates in `yyyyMMdd` format and I need it in `'MM/dd/yyyy'` format.

```
SELECT dt, 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt, 'MMddyyyy')), 1, 10) AS date) 
FROM timetable
```

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working with your current code sample or what output you are currently getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for cast and substring.Specify the dateformat for dt in `unix_timestamp()` and the desired dateformat for `from_unixtime()`

```
select 
       dt,
       from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt,'yyyyMMdd'),'MM/dd/yyyy') 
from timetable;
```

Comment: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:30 missing EOF at '(' near 'from_unixtime' i am getting this error

Comment: Probably this is a junk character or an extra tab while copy pasting your query. The above answer is correct.